# EXPORT VARIABLES FROM SCRIPTS

Tags: variables, tags, export, gitlab-ci, artifacts

I have some issues with GitLab: how do I export a variable from a script, what I want to use in different stages. I tried this code but it didn't work. Can anyone help me please?
I tried [this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q89HA.png) to export variable from createtag.sh

Comment: Generally, it's best to put the text in your post instead of an image of text. Code can be put between backtics (next to the 1 key on many keyboards) like "```" here's some code "```" (but without the quotes). Also, can you provide the content of the script? This question is unanswerable without it.

Comment: This issue of variable expansion inside the CI config is quite complex. [This issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1809) describes what you want to do, but unfortunately it has not been resolved yet. The [status update](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1809#status-update-2021-03-16) will give you a clearer idea of what is currently possible.